# How could I display a dataframe from Sublime Text into a console to better explore it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sublimetext3, spyder

I am entering into the Data Science world and I have an easy question:

I am coding Python in Sublime Text. When I plot my dataframe there I do not get a terminal where I can explore the whole data (like in Spyder). Instead what I get is the df cut off. I can explore it by using some commands like `.head(20)`/`.tail(20)`/etc... and specifying the columns that I want to be shown, but it's kind of annoying and you may not find some variables that need to be cleaned by doing that.

Other options (like the settings `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`, `pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)`, etc...) do not work if the dataframe is quite big.

Does anyone know what could I do to display the whole dataframe outside Sublime Text to explore it?

Ty very much!